# obj-c : iphone dateformatter in 12-hours clock format

Tags: iphone, objective-c, date-format

i want in my application to use the 12 hour clock format so the user can write 15:00
for 3:00 pm so i don't need to create a button am and pm. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Probably you want to use the 24 hour clock format instead of the 12 hour format. So use a NSDateFormatter with H in the format string.
Using one of the predefined formats will end up using your systems localization which probably is the 12 hour format.

```
NSDateFormatter *inputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[inputFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
```